# How can i put an Adapter in a Bundle?

Tags: java, android

Today I received the following error:

> Unable to instantiate fragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Because my fragment constructor is not empty, I submitted an adapter to show some data in my `ListFragment` about the constructor. So I must write an function to save the adapter in a bundle, but how can I handle this?

```
public class AllMedicationsFragment extends ListFragment {
    MyAdapter myAdapter;

        public static final MyFragment newInstance(MyAdapter adapter) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl  = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.put??(adapter);
myFragment.setArguments(bdl);
return myFragment;
    }
```

I get this error ever since I implemented a `TimePickerFragment`, called in another Activity.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass an adapter as an argument to the fragment?

Comment: Because i fill the adapter with data in another activity

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong and unnecessarily coupling the fragment's implementation and that activity.  Instead you should return the data from that activity and pass the data into the adapter.

Comment: Why not pass the data you fill it with instead of the adapter itself?

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback , befor the listfragment i show the adapter in a normal activity , i try to move my fill function in my fragment class

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't.  There's 0 reason or sense to pass an adapter into a fragment.  If you think you need to, you almost certainly have your architecture screwed up.  An adapter is tied to a view, only the fragment owning that view should access it.

If you're trying to do something like save your state in the case of being killed, the correct thing to do is save either the data you're mapping to the list or the data needed to recreate that (like the url to refetch) and create a new adapter when restarted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to put the data an adapter manages into a bundle.

That's where Parcelables come in handy.

You can write a custom adapter to manage a list of Parcelables.  Something like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Parcelable[] mAdapterData;

    public MyAdapter(Parcelable[] wrappedData){
        mAdapterData = wrappedData;
    }

    public Parcelable[] dataAsParcelableArray(){

        // create your array and return it.
    }

}
```

Then do something like:

```
Bundle bdl  = new Bundle(1);
bdl.putParcelableArray("YOUR_KEY", adapter.dataAsParcelableArray());
```